# Cannot add user to Jenkins (Hudson)

Tags: jenkins, hudson, account

I installed stand alone Jenkins installer.
It is available on localhost:8080.

But I cannot understand how to add new account to it.
I tried "Configure Jenkinks" -> "enable security" and etc. from 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup

**But I stil cannot find where exactly I should type username and password for new account.**

This is instruction from wiki:

> Click "login" link at the top right portion of the page
>   Choose "create an account"

There is no "create an account" button. I didn't find this button anywhere!
Where this form is located?

Comment: OK, I clarified it by myself.
Be sure, "Jenkins's own user database" and "registration" options are enabled in security settings. 
Then "create account" button appears on login page.

Comment: Please mark your comment as answering the question.

Comment: @tmporaries your comment should be posted as answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

While you enabled security select  Jenkins’s own user database under Access Control, mark Allow users to sign up. restart jenkins, you will get sign up option through which you can add users.

Comment: That's quite an oversight. It looks like when Jenkins comes out of the box nowadays the radio buttons in that section do not have anything selected by default. The Wiki has an old screenshot I guess I can take it upon myself to update right now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just installed Jenkins and you're logged in as "admin", you have to click on "Manage Jenkins", then "Manage Users"

Comment: and then "Create user" in left menu. Thanks for your answer